# How much RAM is needed for $2^{14}$ square grid of double numbers?

Tags: computer-science, matlab

How is calculated the memory that is needed for matrix of $2^{14}$ by $2^{24}$ double precision real numbers ?

Matlab stops responding with 32Gb ram.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A double precision number requires $8$ bytes of storage. The total number of bytes needed is then the number of double precision numbers multiplied by the number of bytes needed to store each. We have
\begin{equation}
\text{# bytes } = 8\cdot2^{14}\cdot2^{24} = 2^3\cdot2^{14}\cdot2^{24} = 2^{41},
\end{equation}
which is approximately $2.2$ Terabytes.

Comment: Thank you. So is it 550Gb.